# Why does System.Random always return the same number?

Tags: c#, .net

Using System.Random the below always returns 0. I need a random number between 0 and 1. It always returns 0 I would expect some distribution O's and 1's. Thanks

```
Random random = new Random();

int randomInt = random.Next(0, 1)
```

Comment: "I need a random number between 0 and 1" - Then why capture the result in an `int` ?

Comment: I will use the below thanks... mark as answer the answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Random random = new Random();

int randomInt = random.Next(0, 2)
```

The Max-Value will not be reached...

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation for this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx

The number range returned will be from zero to zero. Greater or equal to the first value and less than the second value.

Answer (score 2):

The upper bound is exclusive and won't be reached.

Answer (score 2):

`Random.Next` will return an `int`, that's why you always get `0`. Use `Random.NextDouble` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try random.NextDouble(). There is no int between 0 and 1.